# How to schedule app to lauch including it's GUI

Tags: cron, openoffice.org, schedule

I have a  calc spreadsheet that I'm trying to automate.  When open, it collects data, calculates, saves itself and exits.

So I created a script to call this.

```
soffice --calc --norestore Updater.ods
```

If I run the script `./updater.sh calc` opens and does what its supposed to do :)

However, when I put it in `crontab` or `fcrontab`

```
00     15     *     *     *       export DISPLAY=:0 && /path/updater.sh
```

I can see the process is running, but it doesn't complete any of the actions that it would if the GUI opened.   And running the script from terminal opens the gui, but with cron the gui is not opened.   So I'm wondering if it is possible to open an app (and it's gui) with cron or another scheduler?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try without the &&

```
00 15 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 /path/updater.sh
```

I hope this helps

Comment: You shouldn't have `export` either, if you remove `&&`.

Comment: It worked using the following: (no export or &&)
`00 15 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /path/updater.sh`

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, to schedule graphic tasks, to.

In Orage, the calendar app (double click on the clock in the system panel), doubleclick on a single day.

Select a event, new. Give it a name, here maybe 'updater'. Set the time to 15:00.

Now choose tab: Reminder, Application, use:  /path/updater.sh 
Deactivate sound and other unsound options.

Now choose tab: Repetition, Frequency, daily, 1

I have a German UI, so maybe my translation for the tabs doesn't fit.